# why does it say that variable fc may not have been initialized?

Tags: java, jgrasp

```
`import java.util.Scanner;
public class Shipping
{
public static void main (String []args)
{
   Scanner kb= new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.print("What is the weight of the package in pounds?  ");
   double wop= kb.nextDouble();
   System.out.print("How far is the package being shipped in miles?  ");
   double d= kb.nextDouble();
   double fc;
   int sc;
      if(d%500 !=0) sc= (int)d/500+1; 
      else sc = (int)d/500;
      if(wop<=2)
      fc= 1.10*sc;
         else if (wop>2&&wop<=6)
         fc= 2.20*sc;
            else if (wop>6&&wop<=10)
            fc= 3.70*sc;
               else if (wop>10)
               fc= 3.80*sc;
   System.out.print("The final shipping price is $"+fc+"");
}
}`
```

I keep getting the result that the variable fc might not have been initialized can someone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `double fc;` to `double fc = 0;`.

You know that `fc` will be assigned a value because one of the `if` statements will be `true`, but the compiler does not know this. You just need to give `fc` a dummy value so that the compiler can see that it will definitely have a value when you try to print it.